# How to create a SQL Server 2005 connection string for WEBServer?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, aspnetdb

How to create a SQL Server 2005 connection string .... if my site path on server is

```
d:\DZHosts\LocalUser\volvo\www.volvo.somee.com
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736084/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for detailson how to write a connection string then I would suggest looking at: http://www.connectionstrings.com